Map projections using ggplot
I used Chatgpt to make a plot based on the following:
Using R, I want to create an array with 50x50 grid cells  with 10 degrees spacing east-west (x coordinate) and 10 degrees north-south (y coordinate) extending from 20 degrees west to 40 degrees east and from 30 degrees north to 70 degrees north. I would like a plot that fills the grid cells with colors indicating the values. I want this plotted on top of a map showing country and coastal boundaries. The plot could be saved as a png file. I want the colors to be transparent (alpha=0.4).
I received the following code that works fairly ok, but when asking for another map projection (Lambert) that dont oversize the northern region so much, it fails sompletely. Is it not possible to use this way of plotting with e.g. Lambert proj?
# Install and load necessary packages. Are already installed
#install.packages(c("ggplot2", "sf", "rnaturalearth", "rnaturalearthdata"))
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)

# Define the grid parameters
x_range <- seq(-20, 40, length.out = 50)
y_range <- seq(30, 70, length.out = 50)

# Create a data frame with grid coordinates
df <- expand.grid(lon = x_range, lat = y_range)
df$value <- runif(nrow(df), min = 0, max = 100)  # Assign random values to each grid cell

# Prepare the world map data
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

# Plot the data
plot <- ggplot() +
   geom_tile(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = value), alpha = 0.4) +    
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", midpoint = 50, 
                   name = "Value", guide = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 10, barheight = 0.5)) +
  geom_sf(data = world, fill = NA, color = "black") +  # Add country boundaries
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-20, 40), ylim = c(30, 70), expand = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal(base_family = "sans") +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    text = element_text(color = "black"),
    axis.title = element_blank(),  # Remove axis titles
    axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
    legend.position = "bottom"  # Position the legend at the bottom
  ) +
  labs(title = "Geographical Map with Grid Cell Values")

 # Save the plot as a PNG file with custom width and height
 ggsave("map_plot.png", plot = plot, width = 10, height = 8, dpi = 300)



{sf} comes with st_make_grid() to build regular grids.
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)

set.seed(42)
# make 50x50 WGS84 grid, bounded by defined bbox,
# turn geometry set (sfc) into sf object with a `value` column,
# transform to target projection (ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe, https://epsg.io/3035)
grid_sf <-
  st_bbox(c(xmin = -20, ymin = 30, xmax = 40, ymax = 70 ), crs = "WGS84") |> 
  st_make_grid(n = 50) |>
  st_sf(geometry = _, value = runif(50*50, min = 0, max = 100)) |>
  st_transform(crs = 3035)

# countries, WGS84
world_sf <- ne_countries(scale = "medium")

# coord_sf limits in EPSG:3035, 
# though note how output is still bounded by rectangle and not by trapezoid or 
# projected grid_sf outline
xlim_3035 <- st_bbox(grid_sf)[c(1,3)]
ylim_3035 <- st_bbox(grid_sf)[c(2,4)]

ggplot() +
  # first sf layer (grid_sf) sets coord_sf's crs, can be overridden, if needed
  geom_sf(data = grid_sf, aes(fill = value), color = NA, alpha = .4) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", midpoint = 50) +
  geom_sf(data = world_sf, fill = NA, color = "black") +
  coord_sf(xlim = xlim_3035, ylim = ylim_3035, expand = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal()


Created on 2024-06-24 with reprex v2.1.0

Many thanks! Just what I was looking for. ChatGPT never managed to suggest this ...

The problem is that geom_tile is using raw numbers representing degrees as its co-ordinates. When you convert between projections, the co-ordinate system is no longer in degrees, so geom_tile no longer lines up with the map.
The most comprehensive way to deal with this is to create the tiles as an sf dataframe. This requires a bit of calculation, but looks something like this:
x_range <- seq(-20, 40, length.out = 50)
y_range <- seq(30, 70, length.out = 50)

df <- expand.grid(lon = x_range, lat = y_range)

df <- lapply(seq(nrow(df) - 1), function(i) {
  if(df$lon[i + 1] < df$lon[i]) return(NULL)
  st_polygon(list(cbind(
    c(seq(df$lon[i], df$lon[i + 1], length = 10),
      rep(df$lon[i + 1], 10),
      seq(df$lon[i + 1], df$lon[i], length = 10),
      rep(df$lon[i], 10)),
    c(rep(df$lat[i], 10),
      seq(df$lat[i], df$lat[i] + 40/49, length = 10),
      rep(df$lat[i] + 40/49, 10),
      seq(df$lat[i] + 40/49, df$lat[i], length = 10))
      )
  ))}) |> 
  st_sfc(crs = 'WGS84') |>
  st_sf() |>
  setNames('geometry') |>
  `st_geometry<-`("geometry")
  
df$value <- runif(nrow(df), min = 0, max = 100)

Now we can create a plot with the exact area we want by cropping the world map to a pre-specified "rectangle":
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

sf_use_s2(FALSE)

plot <- st_polygon(x = list(cbind(c(seq(-20, 40, length = 100),
                            rep(40, 100),
                            seq(40, -20, length = 100),
                            rep(-20, 100)), 
                          c(rep(30, 100),
                            seq(30, 70, length = 100),
                            rep(70, 100), seq(70, 30, length = 100))))) |>
  st_sfc(crs = 'WGS84') |>
  st_intersection(world) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = df, aes(fill = value), alpha = 0.4, color = NA) +    
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", 
                       midpoint = 50, name = "Value", 
                       guide = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 10, barheight = 0.5)) +
  geom_sf(fill = NA, color = "black", linewidth = 0.3) + 
  theme_minimal(base_family = "sans") +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    text = element_text(color = "black"),
    axis.title = element_blank(), 
    axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
    legend.position = "bottom"  
  ) +
  labs(title = "Geographical Map with Grid Cell Values")

All of this simply gives us the same plot as we had originally:
plot


Except we can now transform it to any projection we like using coord_sf. For example, we get a nice Lambert projection with crs = 3416:
plot + coord_sf(expand = FALSE, crs = 3416) 


Or a Mollweide projection like this:
plot + coord_sf(expand = FALSE, crs = "+proj=moll") 


Note how the tiles deform correctly based on the projection given.
